# Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ...dexDebug

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm currently facing a problem when I try to run my app on android studio, I get the following error

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':ehtprofs_beta_module:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

After looking fot the error online I found that it's caused by a redundancy in class imports for any external jars added to the projects, but I've only added 2:

- commons-codec
- son-simple

which have no classes in common. But in my project libraries I have the following:

- appcompat-v7-22.2.1
- design-22.2.1
- support-annotations-22.2.1
- support-v4-22.2.1

So I'm left wondering that maybe the redundancy is caused by the above 4 libraries. Does anyone know if this is really the cause ? If there are common classes among these libraries ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new project and started adding one library at a time, but after adding them all everything was surprisingly still working fine, then when I changed the java version to 1.8

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

I started getting the error I was previously facing, so when I switched it back to 1.7 my app started working. So I guess there was a compatibility issue between the JDK and the gradle version.